# Tracking events like tracking periods?

Tags: data-visualization, graphs, health

Is there an app that help me tracking change like tracking women's periods? It should let me assign the days when an event happens, and then make a graph so I can see how frequent it is. It's just like tracking period apps, but I have a lot of "periods".

I have a wide range of platform to use: Windows, Linux, web, iOS, Android. It should be free. And I want to support FOSS also, but this is optional.

Comment: Does someone just delete my other answer? I haven't read the comment explaining why it should be deleted

Answer (score 1):

I find [Way of Life](http://wayoflifeapp.com/#about) (iOS) is pretty good. Although you can only track 3 "periods" for free. You can pay $4 to get a pro version.

[image]